# Laravel Eloquent overriding static find method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Due to internationalization and other rules in place, when we retrieve an object from the database, we need to add additional fields to the object (for instance, name, value in local currency, etc) that require a bit of 'logic'.

I'd love to be able to do

```
$product = Product::find(1);
echo $product->name;
echo $product->local_cost;
```

These are items that will be displayed and not saved so I'm not overly concerned in maintaining the relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a getXXXAttribute() [Accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) methods to your model

```
class Product extends BaseModel {

    public function getLocalCostAttribute()
    {
        return $this->base_cost * $this->exchange_rate;
    }
}
```

Then you can access that "property" using

```
echo $product->local_cost;
```

Note that the new method uses `local_cost` as part of the method name, but switched to "camel case" from "snake case"

Comment: are you serious? there's support for that.. wow. I went to see why I hadn't read that in the documentation and I just found it. Turns out I was referencing old documentation. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Most of the documentation shows Accessors being used to manipulate properties that do actually exist in your model (e.g. case-formatting first name); but they can easily be used for simulating additional properties

Comment: Right exactly. Thanks a lot Mark. I love Laravel.